# How do Bitcoin clients know how many new bitcoins to mint when creating a block?

Tags: mining-reward, reward-schedule

I understand that lucky clients that create blocks get some transaction fees and are allowed to mint a few new bitcoins to keep for themselves.

How do clients know how many new bitcoins to mint for themselves when creating a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mining reward is the sum of two parts: Transaction fees and block reward.

The transaction fees are the sum of the transaction fees of the transactions that the miner is trying to validate.

The block reward follows a predetermined schedule: It started with 50 BTC per block and halves every 210,000 blocks. According to [the bitcoin.it-FAQ](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#How_long_will_it_take_to_generate_all_the_coins.3F) the last block to have a block reward will be block #6,929,999.

The protocol includes a check that will reject blocks which assign more than *block reward + transaction fees* in the coinbase transactions. Assigning less is valid, however, [the difference will be lost](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13336/if-a-coinbase-reward-isnt-fully-spent-can-the-coins-ever-be-recovered/13339#13339).

Answer (score 2):

The block reward schedule is part of the Bitcoin specification. It started out at 50 Bitcoins per block and halves every 210,000 blocks.

Comment: Depending on how you define "mint", claimed fees from transactions in the block may need to be included as well.