# Question about mining algo

Tags: transaction-fees, mining-reward, algorithms

Lets say mining block is generated in 18:00, next block is generated after 10 minutes in 18:10 by user GENERATOR_18_10

As I understand, all transaction fees (for transactions included in 18:10) will come to the user GENERATOR_18_10?

Or, in other words, user GENERATOR_18_10 can point all fees in his wallet?

Comment: Yes, see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17999/how-exactly-do-new-bitcoins-come-into-existence/18003#18003

Comment: thanks, just checking :) And difficulty is just count of zero at start? :)

Comment: Difficulty started out at 1. See [How is difficulty calculated?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5840/5406)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the block will describe how to allocate the block reward, currently 25 bitcoins, of the discovered block.

They write this in the coinbase field of the block. Sometimes, the block reward and fees are sent to multiple addresses, like in P2Ppool mining operations.